# Merge consecutive identical rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

So I have the following table.

```
DATE                price_usd  price_eur
------------------------------------------
2019-11-06 00:00:00 0.00000000  0.01000000
2019-11-06 00:00:00 0.01000000  0.00000000
2019-11-05 00:00:00 0.00000000  0.00000000
```

How can I merge the first to rows when selecting, so I can get

```
DATE                price_usd  price_eur
------------------------------------------
2019-11-06 00:00:00 0.01000000  0.01000000
2019-11-05 00:00:00 0.00000000  0.00000000
```

Comment: Never more than one non-zero value in a column for a day? No negative values?

Comment: Define 'consecutive'

Comment: Same date?  Why show hh:mm:ss if always midnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use group by

```
select date,max(price_usd),max(price_eur)
from table group by date
```

Comment: Or do you need SUM instead of MAX?

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by`:

```
select date, max(price_usd), max(price_eur)
from t
group by date;
```